# How can the PCs make money in an urban adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, waterdeep-dragon-heist

I'm running Dragon Heist for my players, and I've come to a bit of a roadblock so to speak. In chapter 2, the PCs are meant to open and run their own tavern, however it costs 1000gp+ to even open it, let alone pay to operate it. They're only level 2, and seeing as it's the middle of Waterdeep there aren't exactly dragons' hoards or goblin outposts to plunder. How are they meant to make the money in this situation? The book doesn't really offer any specific ways, and I'd rather not run a session based entirely around crafting and performance rolls.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.